# Mongodb c# 2.0 select from inner arrays

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

i have this kind of documents in my db:

```
{ 
  _id: ObjectId,
  arr1: [
          {
            _id: 1,
            name: "David"
          },
          {
            _id: 2,
            name: "John"
          },
          ...
         ],
  arr2: [
         {
           _id:100,
            name: "Ron"
         },
         {
           _id:150,
            name: "Chris"
         },
         ...
        ]
}
```

i want to use the 2.0 C# driver for Mongodb and select a specific inner element.

For example:

```
getPerson(id, personId)
```

will return only the person from the correct document (the document with the given id) by checking both arr1 and arr2.

How do i perform this action on the server (not by getting the document first and querying the inner arrays with C#)?

Answer (score 0):

Restating:  If this is what you seek:

1. Given an "outer" _id, first try to match on that.
2. Then, match on "inner" _id in either arr1 or arr2

then if outer _id is `id` in `getPerson(id, personId)` and
inner _id is `personId` in `getPerson(id, personId)`
then this should yield the overall document that satisfies #1 and #2:

```
c = db.foo.find({
    "_id": outerId,
    $or: [
 {"arr2._id": innerId},
 {"arr1._id": innerId},
          ]});
```

Comment: from what i understand that will give me the element that one of its arrays contains the person, i want it to get the person (the element in one of the arrays). also i want to do it using the C# 2.0 driver

Comment: This will give you one and only one complete doc where the personId exists in EITHER arr1 or arr2.   The outerId check against _id guarantees one and only one match.   After that, it like "double checking" against material on the inside.     There are plenty of external examples on how to use the C# Filter and Find objects/methods, e.g.
var filterBuilder = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter;
var filter = filterBuilder.Gt("i", 50) & filterBuilder.Lte("i", 100);
await collection.Find(filter).ForEachAsync(d => Console.WriteLine(d));

Comment: but i don't want the doc that contains the element with the given personId, i want to extract the "person" element from the arrays if it exists, meaning the return type will have the next format  
    {
     _id: [id],
     name: [name]
    }